# While developing in the Visual Studio 2013 IDE, CPU spikes and it becomes very laggy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

## The problem

When using Visual Studio 2013, **Ultimate update 5**, the IDE becomes very laggy (not running anything), and CPU spikes eating consistently around 30% up to 100% CPU.

[image: High percentage CPU]

## Particulars (what I am doing when this happens)

This happens quite often and doesn't seem to be dependant upon any specific project. I have tried re-installing (fresh), as well as from scratch (format, reinstall windows, install ONLY visual studio + a very moderate suite of developer controls [2 well known companies (DevExpress, and Telerik)])

What is also very odd, is this happens even when developing a console application, although it takes much longer for this to occur.

The system I am running is more than adequate (according to their specs required), and Visual Studio is really the only application experiencing this lag + cpu spike issue.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate]

(notice the cpu spike to 58%. this was also visual studio doing that in the background)
[image: System Information]

This is not a code issue, but an issue somehow with the IDE itself. What I am hoping for is a solution involving something that I may need to tweak / adjust / disable / etc  which is contributing to this. As an aside, I really have no idea why there are so many handles open when Visual Studio is running. 91k seems quite excessive.

Another issue (pointing it out as it may be related), when publishing a project, after publishing, Visual Studio keeps automatically checking 'Click Once' when I have explicitly disabled it. This needs to be unchecked after every time I publish or else the next publish/compile/test run, results in an 'mscorelib' message complaining that the pdb doesn't exist, even though it does, and I have used it in other projects. What is frustrating about this problem is that I am telling it I don't want the project to be clickonce, and after it builds a non-click once project for publish, Visual Studio enables it effectively making this checkbox useless and wasting valuble time having to do this after each publish. Time, that adds up -- especially with the persistent lag.

I am confident I am not the only one who has experienced this due to reproducing this issue on a fresh and bare setup of both the operating system, and visual studio with nothing else aside from two popular component suites.  As such, this is my attempt to reach anyone else who has experienced this, and if you did find a solution (or cause), to lend a hand to me.

Comment: Which edition, which update version? Are your projects under source control?

Comment: Last time I had such an issue it helped to disable Intellitrace.

Comment: @jessehouwing I disabled git, and that seems to have improved it.  Version / etc are in the second image above.

Comment: Analyze the CPU usage of devenv.exe with WPRUI/WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis Use WPRUI instead of xperf. Run WPRUI select **CPU usage**, it generates PDBs for ngened DLLs. otherwise you see ? in the stack